# Flexbox for responsive card image and content - blog

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make my image and the content next to it to be responsive, currently, on the first breakpoint my image grows in height,

how can I use flexbox that my whole post gets smaller and stay inside my layout without losing the size of the image?

On full screen, it looks like this [Full screen img](https://gyazo.com/031e52524b00f68abee092b19f8d2dd8)
on breakpoint 860px - [Breakpoint img](https://gyazo.com/dcac9370810890d97d4803948a967188) - should look [like this](https://gyazo.com/bbeadebbb916ace68d89063454a2b9a6)

HTML

```
    <main class="main-content main-layout flex column">
      <div class="post flex">
        <img src="img/post1.png" alt="" class="post-img" />
        <div class="post-content flex column">
          <h2 class="post-title uppercase">
            duis aute irure dolor in henderit in voluptate.
          </h2>
          <article class="post-text">
            <p>
              Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
              nisi ut aliquip ex ea commo doconsequat, sunt in culpa qui officia
              deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            <p>
              Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
              cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur...
            </p>
          </article>
          <button class="read-more-btn">
            <span class="capitalize">continue Reading</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
</main>
```

CSS

```
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main-layout {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.main-content {
  border: solid 2px #e1e0e0;
  gap: 70px;
}

.post {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-inline-end: 20px;
}

.post .post-content {
  padding-inline-start: 40px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

/* HELPERS */

/* Flex */

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex.align-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.flex.space-between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (min-width: 860px) {
  .main-layout {
    max-width: 820px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to keep same aspect ratio try adding these two properties

```css
.post-img{
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```